# How to get the method from the system service?

Tags: android, android-source, user-profile, user-management, usermanager

Need method following methods

userCreate(string, int) 
createGuest(string, int) from UserManager class

I have created instance for the class but it not working

UserManager userManager = (UserManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.USER_SERVICE);

Give me suggestion?

Comment: There is no `userCreate()` or `createGuest()` method in [the Android SDK for `UserManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager).

Comment: public UserInfo createUser(String name, int flags) {
         return user;
    } if you look into the UserManager class then you can see the above method

Comment: My point is that they are not part of the Android SDK. Modern versions of Android are actively blocking developers who try to hack into classes like this and access non-`public` methods.